# \AtBeginSection in other document classes like article or book

Tags: beamer, macros, sectioning

I understand that there is `\AtBeginSection` in `beamer` class which allows us to execute a set of commands at the start of each section. As we find in beamer guide,

> **`\AtBeginSection[⟨special star text⟩]{⟨text⟩}`** The given text will be
>   inserted at the beginning of every section. If the ⟨special star text⟩
>   parameter is specified, this text will be used for starred sections
>   instead.

Now in the `article` or `book` class, we find the command `\AtBeginDocument`, but that is all.

Is there anything like `\AtBeginSection` in other document classes like `article` or `book`?

If there is none, is there any chance we can define it?

Comment: What precisely do you need it for?

Comment: @tohecz Exactly as the name suggests, I want some set commands to be executed at the start of each section, mainly to revive some controls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\AtBeginDocument` and friends are called hooks. Applied to your situation, you can see how they are defined usually:

```
\newcommand{\AtBeginSection}[1]{%
\let\savedsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}[2][]{\savedsection[##1]{##2} #1}
}
```

You can use this (once!) to add material right after the start of every section. Maybe it would be better to call the macro `\AtEverySection`...